# Load component but without part of its structure

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load in a view a component which is: `<Loader/>`

The thing is that the component is structured like this:

```
<Loader.BoxTitleContainer>
      <Loader.MainTitle>
        <Loader.Title>{`Loading...`}</Loader.Title>
      </Loader.MainTitle>
</Loader.BoxTitleContainer>
    <Loader.Container className={'loader'}>
      <Loader textDisabled={true} />
</Loader.Container>
```

What I actually want to do is to load `<Loader/>` the way it is but preventing it to load `<Loader.BoxTitleContainer>` without altering the structure (which is on top of this paragraph). How can I do it? Any solid example?

Thanks!

Comment: This is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a **boolean prop** to your *Loader* component which would render BoxTitleContainer if set to true, and vice versa, like this:

```
const { showBoxTitleContainer } = this.props;

return (
    {showBoxTitleContainer && <Loader.BoxTitleContainer>
      <Loader.MainTitle>
        <Loader.Title>{`Loading...`}</Loader.Title>
      </Loader.MainTitle>
    </Loader.BoxTitleContainer>}
    <Loader.Container className={'loader'}>
      <Loader textDisabled={true} />
    </Loader.Container>
);
```

The alternative would be to divide the structure in two React components:

```
// BoxTitleContainer
<Loader.BoxTitleContainer>
    <Loader.MainTitle>
        <Loader.Title>{`Loading...`}</Loader.Title>
    </Loader.MainTitle>
</Loader.BoxTitleContainer>

// LoaderContainer
<Loader.Container className={'loader'}>
    <Loader textDisabled={true} />
</Loader.Container>
```

You can't accomplish this without altering the structure.

Answer (score 0):

if Loader.BoxTitleContainer is your's component, you can introduce a property, let say, **hide**, or if that is 3dparty component see it's possible properties (sometimes it is better just to see the source code, as docs sometims missing some details). Inside the  BoxTitleContainer there should be a check for value of **hide** for the decision on either render the component or not.

In this approach you can easily control your title like (see **hide={this.props.hideTitle || false}** as a property for BoxTitle):

```
<Loader.BoxTitleContainer hide={this.props.hideTitle || false}>
  <Loader.MainTitle>
    <Loader.Title>{`Loading...`}</Loader.Title>
  </Loader.MainTitle>
</Loader.BoxTitleContainer>
<Loader.Container className={'loader'}>
  <Loader textDisabled={true} />
</Loader.Container>
```

and then in your `<Loader />` you can do `<Loader hideTitle={true}/>`

If the component is not yours and it doesn't have any similar to *hide* property, then you can do HOC component to wrap this BoxTitle one and then introduce the *hide* propery in it.